# Can one repeat the name of Hashem when reading from the Torah to get the singing note right (meaning unchanged)?

Tags: mistakes, torah-reading, shemos-sacred-names

Someone reading from the Torah gets the singing note (trop) wrong for one of the names of Hashem, in a manner which does not change the meaning of the verse. He then does not need to go back and repeat the name of Hashem to get the note right ([O Ch 142 (1) MB [4]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=44)).

Is he allowed to correct himself in this case? Though [O Ch 142 (1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=44) says we don’t make him go back, it does say that we rebuke him אין מחזירין אותו אבל גוערין בו; can he correct himself if he wishes to maybe reduce the rebuke?

If he can correct himself, how should he do it? Can he repeat just the name with the right trop or must he complete the possuk and then repeat it with right trop (as I have heard on occasions)?

(See also [this parallel question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33933/759).)

Comment: He would have to finish the *pasuk* and start again. Repeating just the name would be saying Hashem's name in vain (since he was already *yotze*).