# Can one repeat the name of Hashem when reading from the Torah to get the singing note right (meaning changed)?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, torah-reading, shemos-sacred-names

Someone reading from the Torah gets the singing note (trop) wrong for one of the names of Hashem, in a manner which changes the meaning of the verse. He then needs to go back and repeat the name of Hashem to gets the note right ([O Ch 142 (1) MB [4]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=44)).

How should he do it? Can he repeat just the name with the right trop or must he complete the possuk and then repeat it with right trop (as I have heard on occasions)?

(See also [this parallel question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33910/759).)

Comment: here is a link that explains the laws of krias haTorah and the reason I deleted my answer was b/c it is called a common misconception to think once someonesays Gd's name they must finish the posuk and repeat it... http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/726345/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Lesser_Known_Laws_of_Torah_Reading#

Comment: @Dude http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14511&st=&pgnum=119

Comment: The ball korei must be a serious ball medakdek in all the tunes if he is being corrected on a tune for a shem hashem that changes the meaning

Answer (score 2):

The issue to stop without finishing the Pasuk would be that you are creating an ending for a pasuk   in a place where  Moshe Rabbenu didn't end it. The Chayei Adam (5:2) , with the interpretation of the Chesed Leavrohom (216) and the Tzitz Eliezer (12:40) , writes that this is only an issue if you would intentionally do so, but if your intention is to complete the pasuk differently (in a case where you only repeat the second half of a pasuk) or in a case where you repeat the full pasuk without first completing it (if the mistake was in middle of the pasuk and the reader goes back to the beginning before the completion) then this issue doesn't apply. The Chayei Adam explicitly says that this is the case even if the Shem Hashem is repeated.

The Tzitz Eliezer concluded that the prevalent  custom is that if a mistake was made after the shem hashem was said, the pasuk is completed and only then repeated. But if there is another Shem Hashem still coming up in the pasuk, one should apply the heater of the Chayei Adam and stop at that point (prior to the next Shem hashem) and start over

For further reference  -הקריאה בתורה והלכותיה , עמוד קסט

Comment: Many don't have any problem לכתחילה stopping at the middle of a verse in case of an error, and in my personal experience this is how most people do it.